# how to avoid Alamofire change parameters automatically?

Tags: ios, swift, get, alamofire

It's strange when i see in Xcode console, the output of URL parameters are not the same as i inputted using Alamofire,

1. parameters' sequence changed
2. and extra numbers **"25"** added into  parameter "key",

Pls see following original code:

```
    let weatherURL="http://open.weather.com.cn/data/"
    let params=["areaid":"\(areaid)","type":"forecast_v","date":"\(time)","appid":"1eb583","key":"\(URLEncodeKey)"]

    Alamofire.request(.GET, weatherURL, parameters: params)
        .responseJSON { (request, response, json, error) in
            if((error) != nil){
                println(request)
                println("Error:\(error)")
            }else{
                println(request)
                println(json)
            }
    }
```

the output of URL in console:

> key:2v7eK8AlzynX%2BuLBgw7DU74f8S0%3D
>
> NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7fe3f14a1bf0 { URL: http://open.weather.com.cn/data/?appid=1eb583&areaid=101020900&date=201507211626&key=2v7eK8AlzynX%252BuLBgw7DU74f8S0%253D&type=forecast_v }

These two problems caused error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid value around character 0.)

Thus i can't get the data from API. But when the URL is corrected from above two problems by hand, means URL:

> http://open.weather.com.cn/data/?areaid=101020900&type=forecast_v&date=201507211626&appid=1eb583&key=2v7eK8AlzynX%2BuLBgw7DU74f8S0%3D
>
> 1. change the parameters sequence as the same in constant "params",
> 2. and remove extra "25".

Then it works, i can see the responding data from API in web browser.

So, please, what problems i ignored in my code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that you are seeing the following on the console:

```
key:2v7eK8AlzynX%2BuLBgw7DU74f8S0%3D
```

You're not showing us how this `key` value was generated, but that's very strange, because that string is percent escaped, and it shouldn't be. If you remove the percent escapes, you see something like

```
key:2v7eK8AlzynX+uLBgw7DU74f8S0=
```

And that is a well formed base64 string.

The thing is, if you're using Alamofire, you should not be percent escaping it (Alamofire does that for you). In fact, that's why you're seeing the extra "25", because it's percent escaping your key string a second time, replacing the `%` characters with `%25`.

Bottom line, find out why the `key` is already percent escaped, and prevent that from happening. (Or, remove the percent escapes with `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` before adding it to the dictionary; but it's better to prevent the percent escaping rather than adding and then replacing the percent escapes.) If you pass it the `2v7eK8AlzynX+uLBgw7DU74f8S0=` value in the `parameters` dictionary, everything should be fine.

---

Regarding of the `parameters` collection: The `parameters` is a dictionary, and unlike arrays, dictionaries are not ordered collections, and they won't preserve the order you specify the keys. Fortunately, the parameters in HTTP requests in standard web servers are not order-specific, either, so this is not an issue.

Comment: Thank you very much, Rob. After remove stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding, the "key" print as what it should be. But do you know why the sequence of "let params" has been changed? For example, ""areaid"" is the 1st parameter in "let params", but then become the 2nd parameter in console. The URL only works when i adjust the sequence as API request.

Comment: @steve As outlined in my revised answer, dictionaries are not sorted collections, that's why the order changes. You say that your API only works if you adjust the sequence?!? That's very, very unusual. Are you 100% sure about that? Standard web servers do not care about the order the parameters appear. The only time I've heard that it does matter is when connecting to some integrated circuit device that doesn't have a proper web server, but has something kludgy HTTP-like interface. But well-written web servers do not care about the order of the parameters.

Comment: yes, i tried to change parameters many times for testing, only the fixed  sequence requested in API can be used and return the json data successfully. My back step is pass the parameters into URL directly and removed the "parameters" from Alamofire. Like this, 
'let weatherURL="http://open.weather.com.cn/data/?areaid=\(areaid)&type=forecast_v&date=\(time)&appid=1eb583&key=\(base64String)"'
'Alamofire.request(.GET, weatherURL)'
It's an official National Weather API, the reason i use it because i think it should be accurate and

Comment: the reason i use it because i think it should be accurate and punctuality, but actually it's ugly and stupid. I think i should change to other third API server. Thank you again for your help!